# Modern OpenGL with GLFW3 on Mac OSX 10.8.4 - missing glGenVertexArrays() and glBindVertexArray()?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I'm trying to setup GLFW3 for my OpenGL project on Xcode 5 (Mac OSX 10.8.4). I have successfully installed and linked my project to GLFW3 no problem. I even got a window successfully created with the project, and I were able to detect mouse and keyboard inputs with the window, so I believe that I got GLFW3 hooked up correctly (or at least it seemed so).

However, the problem occured when I tried to draw an object. This was the code snippet where the error showed up:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>    

void LoadObject()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO_myObj); // ERROR : Use of undeclared identifier 'glGenVertexArrays'
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_myObj);     // ERROR : Use of undeclared identifier 'glBindVertexArray'


    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_myObj);                // No error
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_myObj);   // No error

    glBufferData(blah blah blah);      // No error

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);      // No error
    glVertexAttribPointer(blah);       // No error


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);  // No error
    glBindVertexArray(0);              // ERROR : Use of undeclared identifier 'glBindVertexArray'
}
```

So, this led me to believe that somehow GLFW3 failed to link to those functions (?). When I typed "glGen..." to Xcode, I only saw the following 4 functions on the popup window:

```
void glGenBuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint * buffers)
GLuint glGenLists(GLsizei range)
void glGenQueries(GLsizei n, GLuint * ids)
void glGenTextures(GLsizei n, GLuint * textures)
```

So, it was most likely that glGenVertexArrays() was indeed missing from the library.

Similarly for "glBind...", when I type the name to Xcode, only these showed up on the popup window:

```
void glBindAttribLocation(GLuint program, GLuint index, const GLchar * name)
void glBindBuffer(GLenum target, GLuint buffer)
void glBindTexture(GLenum target, GLuint texture)
```

No where did I see the glBindVertexArray() on the list.

So, it seems that glGenVertexArrays() and glBindVertexArray() are missing. But how could they have missed such important functions? So, it's most likely that I myself am missing something here.

I'm just wondering if any one has encountered this issue with GLFW3 with Xcode 5 before? By the way, I'm not using glew or any other OpenGL support stuff. I'm only using GLFW3.

I would appreciate any hint or pointer regarding this issue.

On the side note, which tool (beside glfw) would you recommend to get a window up on a Mac for a modern (shader-based) OpenGL project?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like you included `<OpenGL/gl.h>` instead of `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`. This matters on OS X.

Comment: I didn't even include <OpenGL/gl.h>. According to glfw documentation, glfw included <OpenGL/OpenGL.h> for you. The only includes I have are #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>, #include <fstream> for reading in shaders, and #include<string> for string manipulation. That was it.

Comment: Wow, you got it. Thank you, Andon. I decided to #include <OpenGL/gl3.h>, and it worked! So, GLFW3 should have included "gl3.h", but it didn't (it included "gl.h" instead). Would you please re-post your response as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` on OS X in order to use OpenGL 3.2 core API calls. Be aware that if you include both `<OpenGL/gl.h>` and `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` you may receive a compiler warning, this is because `gl3.h` serves two purposes:

1. Provides the functions, enums and typedefs for core OpenGL 3.2
2. Eliminates deprecated functions, enums and typedefs that are invalid in core OpenGL 3.2

They are effectively mutually exclusive, the proper header depends on the context version you are using:

- MacOS X 10.7+: (OpenGL: **2.1**)

  - `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>`
- MacOS X 10.7+: (OpenGL: **3.2 *core***)

  - `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>`

Comment: Yep, you'll get a compiler warning, but (at this time) since GLFW3 automatically includes "gl.h", there's no way to get around it (not that I know of) if you decide to go with GLFW3.

Comment: THANK YOU! I hit my head for hours against this, trying to figure out why my screen was blank.

Answer (score 14):

GLFW3 includes `<GL/gl.h>` by default.  In order to include `<GL/gl3.h>`, you need to stick `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB` somewhere before `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`

On the Mac OSX installation of GLFW3, using homebrew, the define macro before the the include will use `OpenGL/gl3.h`.  It can be see within the header file:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
 #if defined(GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB)
  #include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
  #if defined(GLFW_INCLUDE_GLEXT)
   #include <OpenGL/gl3ext.h>
  #endif
...
```

The define options are outlined in the [build guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html) for glfw3. This alleviates the compiler warning too.

Comment: That would not be particularly useful on OS X, since Apple does not use the normal `<GL/gl{3}.h>` convention. Their GL framework is called OpenGL, and you have to include `<OpenGL/gl{3}.h>`.

Comment: FYI, today this define on the mac will include `OpenGL/gl3.h`, so it is definitely helpful on a Mac now (as I just solved a problem with this by using it).