# GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART on OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, opengl, glut

i'm using OpenGL 3.2 and GLUT on OSX, and compiling on the command line like such:

```
gcc test.c -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

at the top of my source file, i manually include two headers:

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
```

so far, everything has been fine and dandy.  but today i noticed that using GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART gives me an undeclared identifier error...

are there other headers i need to include or other frameworks?  or does apple just not support GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART in their implementation of OpenGL 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not directly including any of the OpenGL headers. `<OpenGL/OpenGL.h>` might sound like it's the OpenGL header, but it actually contains definitions for CGL.

You indirectly get an OpenGL header because `<GLUT/GLUT.h>` includes `<OpenGL/gl.h>`. Unfortunately that's the pre-GL3 header file, which is why you don't have the GL3 level definitions.

The header you want is `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`. You can include it yourself, but will most likely see some warnings because `<GLUT/glut.h>` will still also include the old header, and it will point out possible conflicts. The best I found is to use an include sequence like this:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#define __gl_h_
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

The `#define` corresponds to the header guard in `<OpenGL/gl.h>`, and prevents it from being included.

Apple is deprecating GLUT. You have to disable additional warnings in OS X 10.9 to prevent it from complaining about using GLUT. It also doesn't have support for creating newer contexts than GL 3.2.

Comment: awesome, thank you...  it's strange that everything worked up until i tried GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART.  i just found this similar question, it's strange because glBindVertexArray() worked perfectly for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825582/modern-opengl-with-glfw3-on-mac-osx-10-8-4-missing-glgenvertexarrays-and-glb

Comment: That's somewhat odd. `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE()` is in `glext.h`, but I only see the core version `glBindVertexArray()` in `gl3.h`. Well, as long as you got it working...

Comment: @RetoKoradi If you're using OpenGL 3, then you will always have the core version of `glBindVertexArray`; no need to use Apple's version.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Sure. The point here was that the poster did not have the GL3 header included, and said that `glBindVertexArray()` was still defined. That's the part that doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: yeah, i think i am probably an idiot... i was able to recreate that poster's problem with the right combination of headers.  thanks again for the help.

Comment: ha, believe it or not it's a difference between using gcc and g++ on OSX 10.8... gcc doesn't warn but g++ does... must be a promiscuous include path.

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with the include path. gcc, when used to compile C code, might not warn about undefined functions by default. In original C, it is legal to use undefined functions, and they default to functions returning an `int`.