# OpenGL 3.x on Macbook Air mid 2012

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glew

I am trying to get an OpenGL/glew program from a template made by my uni lecturer work. He has added this code to his program:

```
if(!GLEW_VERSION_3_1) {
    std::cerr << "Driver does not support OpenGL 3.1" << std::endl;  
    return 1;
}
```

This prints the error on my mac. After some experimenting, I have found out that my mac is actually running OpenGL (2.1 INTEL-8.28.30). I have worked my way around this using a nasty #ifndef **APPLE** before that part of the code, but I cannot do this in the long term.

Is there any way in which I can upgrade to 3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the concept of core and compatibility contexts in OpenGL, and Apple's implementation. You need to make sure the application requests a core profile OpenGL context.

Apple support a compatibility OpenGL context (with support for all of the old deprecated features) up until a maximum of OpenGL 2.1 (plus several extensions).
Apple support a core OpenGL context (with old deprecated features removed) up until a maximum of OpenGL 4.1 (dependent on hardware support, 3.3 on older hardware) with OSX Mavericks. If you download a program called OpenGL Extension Viewer, you can see what you've got available.

When your program creates an OpenGL context, it gets compatibility by default (to avoid breaking old programs). You need to specifically flag that you want a core profile. The way to do this will depend what windowing library you're using. If you happen to be using SDL2, there's just an extra flag to set when creating the context. If using Apple GL directly, you'd need to check their documentation.

See: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts

Note: I notice you're using GLEW. I encountered issues with GLEW and core contexts in the past. This is because it was requesting extension strings using a method that's deprecated (and therefore fails in a core context). It made it look like no extensions were supported. If this happens, refer to the GLEW website, there was an experimental option you could pass to its init to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I needed. The problem happened to be that my program included OpenGL/gl3.h, whereas the both GLEW and freeglut included OpenGL/gl.h. By including both, I got the "best of both worlds" -- access to both gl3 functions and deprecated stuff from 2.1. Although I now have gl3 included, the code in OP still does not work due to glew not noticing the core gl3. This doesn't really matter though, as the gl3 stuff is, in fact, available. I worked around this by #ifndef \_\_APPLE\_\_ <op-code> #endif. Again thanks!

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold: No, you can _not_ mix deprecated functions and modern OpenGL 3.x functions in a single context on OSX, and the header files you include do not matter at all for this. It is unclear what exactly you are doing here, what context versions you have, and what functions are actually called.

Comment: Don't use GLEW on Mac OS. It serves no useful purpose. On Mac OS, you simply include the header for the OpenGL version you want to use, and link against the framework. As @derhass said, you should only include either `gl.h` or `gl3.h`. See this answer for an (ugly) solution for avoiding that both get included when using GLUT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987479/gl-primitive-restart-on-osx-10-8/23987736#23987736.